# How to modify items based on selected items on vuetify data table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Lets the items are:

```
desserts: [
     {
       name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
       calories: 159,
       fat: 6.0,
       carbs: 24,
       protein: 4.0,
       iron: '1%'
    },
    {
       name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
       calories: 237,
       fat: 9.0,
       carbs: 37,
       protein: 4.3,
       iron: '1%'
    },
    {
      name: 'Eclair',
      calories: 262,
      fat: 16.0,
      carbs: 23,
      protein: 6.0,
      iron: '7%'
    }
]
```

I want to add additional property with all objects such as `isActive: true` or `isActive: false` based on the selection. So, if user select `Frozen Yogurt` & `Ice cream sandwich` columns and click on a custom button, `Add Selected` button, I should get the array of the objects like this way:

```
desserts: [
         {
           name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
           calories: 159,
           fat: 6.0,
           carbs: 24,
           protein: 4.0,
           iron: '1%',
           isActive: true
        },
        {
           name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
           calories: 237,
           fat: 9.0,
           carbs: 37,
           protein: 4.3,
           iron: '1%',
           isActive: true
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
          isActive: false
        }
    ]
```

Are there any vuetify way to do this? Or should we do this with pure javascript in the custom function bind with the click event:

```
<v-btn
   @click="sendData"
  >
    Add Selected
</v-btn>
```

How to do this efficiently?

**.... UPDATE: .......**

I think I have achieved the desired output at `console.log(submittedData)`. but I think my `sendData` function is a bit complicated now. Can you please help me to simplify it?

**[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/bGYWoKm)**

Comment: There is an example how to do it - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#row-selection

Comment: Questions seeking code review are *off-topic* on [SO]. They should be asked on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Toby, code reviews don't have to be scoped to the whole project. They can be about rewriting a specific method. In fact, when you scope a code review to the whole project reviewers rarely touch on one particular method, unless it's really bad and affects the rest.

Comment: Yes, but there's _no code_ in this question.  (Later) - Ah, I see there's a _link_ to some code at the end of the question.  On [codereview.se], the code to be reviewed needs to be [present in the question itself](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/75307), not hidden behind a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Looping through desserts
- spread each item with a new isActive property
- assign Boolean return value from the .includes method to isActive

```js
sendData() {

    let result = this.desserts.map((item) => ({ ...item, isActive: this.selected.includes(item) }));
    console.log(result);

}
```

[Code Pen Demo](https://codepen.io/akashno/pen/qBVmyrV)